# CSS h1 tag with span - font-size accumulates; why?

Tags: css, html, font-size

I have h1 tags with a span to have the first word in 1.4em and the rest in 1.2 em. If I write

```
.item.large h1 {
font-size: 1.4em;
padding-top: 0.3em;
margin-left: 0.4em;
}

.item.large h1 span {
font-size: 1.2em; // why is this not taken into account?
}
```

the words in the span are actually even larger than 1.4em, not smaller! Why is this unexpected growth happening and how do I style part of h1 tags correctly? Thanks!

**Edit:** If I use 0,857142857142857em for the span, I visually get 1.2em height, but that's not the way to do it, I'm sure...

Comment: Ah, thank you both; bit 'o math needed then - and rounding of funny numberz. Who was first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because em is a relative unit of measure (to its parent).

Answer (score 10):

**em** size unit is relative to the parent element. You can use **rem** unit to be relative to the document's main unit size, so to the constant one.

For the more information see http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem

Comment: I see... last time I had a rem document was '87 ;) but yes, that sounds like the best solution to sizing. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code on your CSS:

```
#title h1{
display: block;
font: 24px "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #fff;
}
#title h1>span {
display: block;
font-size: 11px;
color: #fff;
}
```

And in your HTML code:

```
<h1 id="title">My Title<br><span>My Second Title</span></h1>
```